# Use same function in multiple subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using two sub domains

```
domain1.mysite.com

domain2.mysite.com
```

I am making both websites in codeigniter (I am very new in it). Some functions are common for both domain. For example Fetch mobile number of store xyz.

```
function get_loggedin_mobile_number()
  {
$loggedinuser=$_SESSION['loggedindetails'];
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->database('storedb');
$ci->db->where('vendoridd',$loggedinuser);
$query=$ci->db->get('enquiryf');
$row = $query->row_array();
$mobilenumber=$row['business_mobile'];
return $mobilenumber;
  }
```

Now in one domain inside 'helpers folder' (in domain1@.ysite.com) I am writing  function  to fetch mobile number of store xyz.

I want use this function in domain2.mysite.com. also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if both domain are on same server..
include file using server path

```
include("/serverpath/file.php");
```